# How to run a python script inside javascript and refresh the view in django

Tags: javascript, python, django, web

I have a python script that takes in some data and manipulates it. However i need it to run on the client side inside the javascript to process some data and refresh the view.

The python file that manipulates data works well as I have tested it inside the IDLE shell

```
 DataManipulation.py

class ModifyData(object):

       #Bunch of functions to manipulate data
```

below is the function used to render the view with url '.../test' which also works perfectly.

```
 views.py

  def test(request):

        template = 'app/test.html'

        file = 'documents/Sample.csv' #File  to be loaded 

        args = {'test': file }

        return render(request, template, args)
```

After loading this page, i use a javascript library that displays the data on the page in a table, the user can then manipulate the data like multiply a column by 3, but where I am stuck is how to take my DataManipulation.py file to modify the data and updates the page with the updated column on a button click

Comment: If this app uses a browser you won't be able to serve and then execute a python script.  Browser security prevents that.  If this is an electron or nwjs app, then the above would be possible.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should pass the data into template, and then use `javascript` to manipulate the data, after that you can use `ajax` to update your page without refresh, example:

```
<!--html-->
<button onclick="deleteUser({{ request.user.pk }})">Submit</button>
<!---->

function deleteUser(userid) {

    var post_data = {
        'userid': userid,
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/deleteuser",// the view function to post
        data: post_data,
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        success: function(result) {
            // do something after post
            ...
        }
    });
}
```

the view function:

```
# url(r'^/deleteuser$', views.delete_user)
def delete_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # do something
        userid = request.POST.get('userid')
        user = User.objects.get(pk=userid)
        # dict contain response data
        response_data = {...}

        # return response
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data),content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: Are you saying that I cant use my python script at all,

Comment: Why are you copying a script to delete a user?

Comment: The question is tagged with django. `$` belongs to the regular expression that is used for routing.

Answer (score 1):

Since executing python client side is not an option, you have two options.

1. re-write ModifyData in Javascript and use it client side.
2. When a user does something like multiply a column by 3:

   - Use client side JS to make an ajax request to the server
   - Have your server call ModifyData, and then return the data to the client
   - have client update view with new data

I would recommend porting your python code to JS, but if that isn't possible #2 will always work. How you implement will just depend on how you manage data in the client.